# Not able to access files outside ASP.net Core application using Virtual Directory

Tags: virtual-directory, asp.net-core-1.0, iis-10

I have hosted ASP.net Core application in IIS, I have added a virtual directory into the wwwroot\images folder. But I am not able to access the contents in the folder. Can anyone help me? I need to share images between multiple ASP.net Core sites, so I tried using Virtual directory.

[image]

Comment: Curious, why do you have a virtual directory under wwwroot?

Comment: @KiranChalla,  In Asp.net Core the wwwroot folder will have all static files like images, pdfs, HTML pages. I have added the Virtual directory to access images outside the Asp.net core project. I want the images folder to be shared between different sites

Comment: to use files under wwwroot you need to set  app.UseStaticFiles(); in Startup class

Answer (score 1):

I fased same problem couple of weeks ago.
If your project is crossplatform you need to use virtual folders like this:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"D:\files"),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/files"),
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false // you make this true or false.
            });
```

seting in iis will not work